# How can I not use Django's admin login view?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-authentication

I created my own view for login. However if a user goes directly to /admin it brings them to the admin login page and doesn't use my custom view. How can I make it redirect to the login view used for everything not /admin?

Comment: Isaac's answer worked perfectly for me. You should accept his answer! :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

From http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2127/—wrap the admin login page with `login_required`.  For example, in `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.login = login_required(admin.site.login)
```

You probably already have the middle two lines and maybe even the first line; adding that fourth line will cause anything that would have hit the `admin.site.login` function to redirect to your `LOGIN_URL` with the appropriate `next` parameter.

Comment: Suppose I'm already logged in as non-staff user. If I then go to `/admin/` I'll still get default login form, because `login_required` won't trigger.

Comment: I have addressed @PēterisCaune's concerns in my own answer.

Answer (score 10):

While @Isaac's solution should reject majority of malicious bots, it doesn't provide protection for professional penetrating. As a logged in user gets the following message when trying to login to admin:

[image: Django re-login prompt]

We should instead use the admin decorator to reject all non-privileged users:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required
from django.contrib import admin
[ ... ]
admin.site.login = staff_member_required(admin.site.login, login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

To the best of my knowledge, the decorator was [added](https://github.com/django/django/commit/08572e8d125da204fab230be5d1fdcc5d8d22256) in 1.9.

Comment: It's entirely possible (likely) that I'm doing something stupid, but when I do this, I end up with a redirect loop where `/admin/login/` redirects to `/admin/login/?next=/admin/login/`, which redirects to `/admin/login?next=/admin/login/%3Fnext%3D/admin/login/`, etc.

Comment: @Isaac it is necessary to pass `login_url` here:
`admin.site.login = staff_member_required(admin.site.login, login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL)`

Comment: OP, do you mind editing your answer to include the information provided by @blueyed to avoid redirects?

Comment: I would just like to add that I have been searching for a solution to this for hours and only your answer achieved what I was trying to do - thanks very much. - Just wondering, is there a way to redirect the non-staff or non-authenticated user to, for example, a 404 page instead of a login page?

Answer (score 9):

I found that the answer above does not respect the "next" query parameter correctly.

An easy way to solve this problem is to use a simple redirect. In your site's urls file, immediately **before** including the admin urls, put a line like this:

```
   url(r'^admin/login$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='my_login_page', permanent=True, query_string=True))
```

Comment: Better yet, `url(r'^admin/login/$', RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.LOGIN_URL, permanent=True, query_string=True)),`.

Comment: Note that if the my_login_page implements a ?next redirect and redirects already logged in users - this will result in a redirect loop. It's important that my_login_page handles this case by allowing already logged in users.

Answer (score 6):

Holá
I found a very simple solution.
Just tell django that the url for admin login is handle by your own login view

You just need to modify the urls.py fle of the project (note, not the application one)

1. In your PROJECT folder locate the file urls.py.
2. Add this line to the imports section
   `from your_app_name import views`
3. Locate this line
   `url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))`
4. Add above that line the following
   `url(r'^admin/login/', views.your_login_view),`

This is an example

```
    from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin

    from your_app import views

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^your_app_start/', include('your_app.urls',namespace="your_app_name")),

        url(r'^admin/login/', views.your_app_login),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

http://blog.montylounge.com/2009/07/5/customizing-django-admin-branding/
([web archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20130129231715/http://blog.montylounge.com/2009/07/5/customizing-django-admin-branding/)

I'm trying to solve exactly this problem and I found the solution at this guys blog. Basically, override the admin template and use your own template. In short, just make a file called login.html in /path-to-project/templates/admin/ and it will replace the admin login page. You can copy the original (django/contrib/admin/templates/login.html) and modify a line or two. If you want to scrap the default login page entirely you can do something like this:

```
{% extends "my-login-page.html" %}
```

There it is. One line in one file. Django is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, tried to use the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186337/115198), but has the same issue as pointed in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779265/how-can-i-not-use-djangos-admin-login-view#comment44407825_13186337).
Then I've did something bit different, pasting here if this would be helpful to someone.

```
def staff_or_404(u):
    if u.is_active:
        if u.is_staff:
            return True
        raise Http404()
    return False

admin.site.login = user_passes_test(
        staff_or_404,
    )(admin.site.login)
```

The idea is that if the user is login, and tried to access the admin, then he gets 404. Otherwise, it will force you to the normal login page (unless you are already logged in)

Answer (score 2):

In your ROOT_URLCONF file (by default, it's urls.py in the project's root folder), is there a line like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
...
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
...
)
```

If so, you'd want to replace include(admin.site.urls) with the custom view you created:

```
(r'^admin/', 'myapp.views.myloginview'),
```

or if your app has its own urls.py, you could include it like this:

```
(r'^admin/', include(myapp.urls)),
```

Comment: To clarify I want to keep using admin, I want only the login admin view to not be used. By replacing the include(admin.site.urls)) I cannot access /admin any more.

Comment: So you want to login to the admin system via the same login view that you use to login to the rest of the system? What is the mechanism that lets the view know whether a user logging in wants a regular login vs admin login? Obv if the user does not have admin credentials they cannot do an admin login, but if they have admin credentials, would they want to see the site as a logged-in user or as a logged-in admin?

Comment: In my case admin users would never need access to non admin parts of the site. So my view redirects them depending on what type of user they are. So yes I want them to see the same login a non admin user would see. As is this already happens if the go to / but if they bookmark something in /admin it would send them to admin's login which is what I don't want to happen.

Comment: So an admin user goes to /, logs in with the common login view that all users see, and is then served the admin view. You're worried that they will bookmark /admin/whatever, and then when they return to that bookmark at a later time, they will get the admin view instead of the common login view. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want all the login code handled by the same view because I have some custom code that deals with Google Apps authentication. It needs to display special messages beyond login succeed or failed sometimes.

Comment: OK, now that I understand your scenario I can say that it's a bit above my knowledge level right now. I can see that admin.site.urls is created in django/trunk/django/contribu/admin/sites.py and I wonder if you could poke around in there and figure out a way to change the login page associated with admin views. Wish I could be of more help!

Comment: Override just the login view: `(r'^admin/login/', 'myapp.views.myloginview'),`. This works for me. Shall I edit the answer?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution with [custom AdminSite class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#customizing-the-adminsite-class):

```
class AdminSite(admin.AdminSite):

    def _is_login_redirect(self, response):
        if isinstance(response, HttpResponseRedirect):
            login_url = reverse('admin:login', current_app=self.name)
            response_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(response.url).path
            return login_url == response_url
        else:
            return False

    def admin_view(self, view, cacheable=False):
        inner = super().admin_view(view, cacheable)

        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            response = inner(request, *args, **kwargs)
            if self._is_login_redirect(response):
                if request.user.is_authenticated():
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
                else:
                    return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path(), reverse('accounts_login'))
            else:
                return response

        return wrapper
```

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect admin login url to the auth login view :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('your_app.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('admin/login/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/accounts/login/?next=/admin/', permanent=True)),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2020, `django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite` has a `login_template` attribute.  So you can just subclass `AdminSite` and specify a custom template i.e.,

```py
class MyAdminSite(AdminSite):
    login_template = 'my_login_template.html'

my_admin_site = MyAdminSite()
```

Then just use `my_admin_site` everywhere instead of `admin.site`.