# Creating a custom login for user changed the login for my Admin. How to prevent that?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a web application where users have to register themselves and create profiles. I am using the "AbstractBaseUser" class provided by Django, as I wanted to add some other fields. Now, when a user logs in, I want the login credentials to be the Mobile number and the password. I created a custom authentication function for this and registered it in my settings.py. The problem is this changed the login to my admin sit, which I want to remain the same.

I followed the tutorial for add custom fields to User from this [link](http://blackglasses.me/2013/09/17/custom-django-user-model/)

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import UserManager



class userInfo(AbstractBaseUser):

    email = models.EmailField('Email address', unique=True,)
    Mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True,)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Landmark = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'Mobile' 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_username()
```

views.py for login page:

```
import datetime
from .forms import userInfoForm, LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from .models import userInfo, orderHistory
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login, authenticate, logout as django_logoutdef Login(request):

"""
Log in view
"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    print ("Step 1")
    if form.is_valid():
        print ("Step 2")
        user = authenticate(Mobile=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
        print ("Step 3")
        if user is None:
            print("No valid user")
        if user is not None:
            print ("Step 3.10")
            if user.is_active:
                print ("Step 4")
                django_login(request, user)
                print ("Step 5")
                return redirect('/i/Home')
else:
    form = LoginForm()
return render_to_response('loginpage.html', {
    'form': form,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms 
from .models import userInfo, orderHistory  
from django.forms import ModelForm


class LoginForm(forms.Form):
"""
Login form
"""
Mobile = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

class Meta:
    fields = ['Mobile', 'password']        `
```

The backend I created:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import check_passwor
from .models import userInfo

class EmailAuthBackend(object):
    """
    A custom authentication backend. Allows users to log in using their            email address.
    """

def authenticate(self, Mobile=None, password=None):
    """
    Authentication method
    """
    try:
        user = userInfo.objects.get(Mobile=Mobile)
        if user.check_password(password):
            return user
    except userInfo.DoesNotExist:
        return None

def get_user(self, user_id):
    try:
        user = userInfo.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        if user.is_active:
            return user
        return None
    except userInfo.DoesNotExist:
        return None
```

And finally the changes I made to settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Registration.userInfo'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['Registration.authBackend.EmailAuthBackend', ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The default backend for Django is `('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)`, which is what the Django admin is using. When you insert the line:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['Registration.authBackend.EmailAuthBackend', ]
```

you're overwriting the default backend, rather than adding a second backend option. Change that line to:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'Registration.authBackend.EmailAuthBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

and your application should pick up the second backend. You may need to trigger the second backend based on logic for whether the first succeeds, see responses to questions like [Django Multiple Authentication Backend for one project, HOW?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17064443/2532070) or [the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/).

Comment: I don't think I've imported AuthenticatioForm like you've mentioned. Though I tried changing the name of the form. Didn't work.
Commenting out the settings worked. I've included all the import statements above.

Comment: @user3573203 changed my answer, hope this helps. Let me know if that's not the solution as I'd like to understand how this works better!

Comment: Hey. I've included the default backend, the admin page hasn't changed. And IT's still asking for "Mobile" when I'm creating a superuser. I haven't tried applying some logic so that the app picks the default backend though.

Comment: I also tried changing the order in which the authentication models have been mentioned hoping that the admin page will pick up the default model first, but it's still the same.

Comment: @chatuur the thing is, other than the issue above, there could be many reasons the admin login has been overridden. It doesn't look like it's in the code you provided above. Take a look at the various ways to alter the default admin: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6779265/2532070. It could be one of these issues. One that stand out is if you have `admin.autodiscover()` somewhere and then overwrite the login. Another is in the templates, in which you can override the default admin template. The issue is likely one of the answers to that question above.